# SQL - subtract items in column from each other, based on ranking in 2nd column and aggregated by a 3rd column

Tags: mysql, sql, presto, rank

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
  `userid` VARCHAR(2),
  `date_accessed` DATE,
  `rank` INT,
  `country` VARCHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO table_1
  (`userid`, `date_accessed`, `rank`, `country`)
VALUES
  ('A.', '2019-01-01', 1, 'US'),
  ('B.', '2019-01-02', 1, 'FR'),
  ('A.', '2019-01-03', 2, 'US'),
  ('A.', '2019-01-04', 3, 'US'),
  ('B.', '2019-01-04', 2, 'FR');
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/caFeo5c4Try1q7FawHN7MC/1

My dataset looks like this:

```
user | date      | rank | state
A.   |2020-01-01 | 1    | NY
A.   |2020-01-04 | 2    | NY
A.   |2020-01-08 | 3    | NY
B.   |2020-01-01 | 1    | CA
B.   |2020-01-02 | 2    | CA
B.   |2020-01-04 | 3    | CA
```

This is the product of a bunch of WITH intermediate_table AS statements — but at this point in my query this is the structure I'm working with.

For each user, I want to subtract the date ranked 1 with the date ranked 2. So for user A, I want to get the DATEDIFF between 1/1 and 1/4. Ideally the output would look like this:

```
user | date_diff  | state
A.   | 3          | NY
B.   | 1          | CA
```

The eventual goal is to get the average date_diff for each country, averaged across all the users for that country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this sample data one way to do it is to `GROUP BY user, state` and use conditional aggregation to subtract the dates:

```
SELECT 
  user, 
  DATEDIFF(
    MAX(CASE WHEN `rank` = 2 THEN date END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN `rank` = 1 THEN date END)
  ) date_diff,
  state
FROM tablename
WHERE `rank` IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY user, state
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1e4dfc850753098b85a9657ba5c5cd2f).
Results:

```
> user | date_diff | state
> :--- | --------: | :----
> A.   |         3 | NY   
> B.   |         1 | CA
```